# JavaScript raw text manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to manipulate raw text:

I have this and I need this: In this raw text list can be allot of items
_cokwr: Mandarinai, _cpzh4: Ananasai, _cre1l: Bulves, _chk2m: Ceburekai, _ciyn3: Alus

i know in raw text allways be like this _code: item,

something like this

- Mandarinai
- Ananasai
- Bulves
- Ceburekai
- Alus

```html
<ul>

<li>Mandarinai</li>
<li>Ananasai</li>
<li>Bulves</li>
<li>Ceburekai</li>
<li>Alus</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: mustache.js is your friend, and all you really need if your jedi force is strong

Comment: Use regex to create <li> items from your input text and place it on the page using jquery.

Comment: do you need to keep the _code? If not and your list is a string, do a str_replace with a regex then prefix the string with <ul> and suffix with </ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a text string:

```
var raw_text = "_cokwr: Mandarinai, _cpzh4: Ananasai, _cre1l: Bulves, _chk2m: Ceburekai, _ciyn3: Alus";
```

Then you can use split:

```
function splitArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  console.log(array[index].split(": ")[1]);
}
var list = raw_text.split(", ");
list.forEach(splitArrayElements);
```